# return to another fragment from sub activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

my app has 3 fragments : fragment-a ,  fragment-b , fragment-c which managed by NavController.
When user work on fragment-a , it will create a sub activity-e.

```
val subActivity = Intent(activity, Activity-e::class.java)
    startActivity(subActivity)
```

normally , after user completed the stuff on activity-e , it will return to it's parent : fragment-a.

```
val parentIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this)
    parentIntent!!.flags =
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
    startActivity(parentIntent)
    finish()
```

But , in some case , it should go to fragment-b.
Is that possible to return to fragment-b from sub activity-e ?
How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. But I wont said that it is "returned". It is more likely to be navigate to fragment-b

Try to avoid using `Intent` for navController as you're using Navigation Component now.

[image]

Comment: Fragments are contained inside Activity. So the things you need to do is to use navController to navigate to that activity-e.

Comment: I have changed my old way ( intent and startactivity) to  the navcontroller's way. It seems ok  in most cases . But , I got a problem when a fragment calls layer 1 activity and , then , layer 1 activity calls layer 2 activity. I can not navigate to correct fragment at layer2 activity.

Comment: if u navigate from later2 activity to layer1 activity, layer1's navController is recreated and the `startDestination` will be the first place to be displayed. Here is a little trick when you navigate back from layer2 actiivty, you can set a condition where layer1's navController directly go to that correct fragment.